# How to create search form using tkinter Python to search from the SQLITE3 Database?

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

I want to use Tkinter to create a search form where the user can input the name they want to see from the SQLite3 database. A database named New_Assignment has all the details about the person. But I am confused about how to connect the Tkinter to the database and use the name to search? This is what I have got so far.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('new_assignment.db')
c = conn.cursor()
from tkinter import *
top = Tk()
top.title('Search form')
person_name = Entry()
person_name.pack(side = RIGHT, expand = True)
mainloop()
```

Comment: This is probably too broad of a question for SO; you may want to go to the python.org page, go to Community, and look for the IRC channel or python-list mailing list. But as a hint: You need to create a button that, when clicked, calls a function. Inside that function, you need to access the contents of `person_name`, which you can do by asking the `Entry` for its text, or by using a Tk `StringVar` as recommended in the Tkinter Book chapter on `Entry`. More generally, if you read the relevant part of the Book and are still stuck, you should have a more specific question that fits here.

Answer (score 0):

To get the text from the `Entry` widget, use the `get()` method (it returns the string in the textbox).

```
name_box = Entry()
name_box.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=True)

person_name = name_box.get()
```

However, you *will* need to add a button as @abarnert says in the comments. Attach this function to it:

```
def get_name():
  global person_name
  person_name =  name_box.get()
  data = c.fetchall()
  print(data)
  for row in data:
      searchlist.append(row)
      var1=str(person_name)
      read_from_db(var1)
```

(Of couse, modify `read_from_db()` to take a variable like so:

```
def read_from_db(var):
    curs.execute("SELECT *" + " FROM personal WHERE Name LIKE (?)", ('%'+var+'%',))
```

)

An example of the code for a button might look like this:

```
button = Button(top, text="Display text", command=get_name)
```

Place it all together:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('new_assignment.db')
c = conn.cursor()

from tkinter import *

top = Tk()
top.title('Search form')

name_box = Entry()
name_box.pack(side = RIGHT, expand = True)

def get_name():
    global person_name
    person_name = name_box.get()
    data = c.fetchall()
    print(data)
    for row in data:
        searchlist.append(row)
        var1=str(person_name)
        read_from_db(var1) 


def read_from_db(var):
    curs.execute("SELECT *" + " FROM personal WHERE Name LIKE (?)", ('%'+var+'%',))


person_name = ""
button = Button(top, text="Display text", command=get_name)
button.pack()


mainloop()
```

Comment: def read_from_db():
        curs.execute("SELECT *" +
              " FROM personal WHERE Name LIKE (?)", ('%'+var1+'%',))
        data = curs.fetchall()
        print(data)
        for row in data:
            searchlist.append(row)

    var1=str(name_box)
    read_from_db()

after I add these code still couldn't retrieve any data?